# Get same line from two textArea?

Tags: java

I have `TextArea1` and `TextArea2`

Inside `TextArea1` I have:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Inside `TextArea2` I have:

```
111
222
333
444
```

I would like append to `TextArea3` like so

```
aaa111
bbb222
ccc333
ddd444
```

---

I tried the following code but it did not work

```
for(String line : textArea1.getText().split("\\n")); String line2 : textArea2.getText()).split("\\n")) {
    textArea3.append("('" + line +"'," + line2);\n");
}
```

Comment: "Not work." is a veeery unspecific description. In what way doesn't it work? I guess it doesn't compile since extended for-loops don't work like you tried to to it. Did you try a traditional for-loop with indices yet?

Comment: What should happen if they have not the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a space `" "` as separator like below.

```
        String[] arr1 = "aaa bbb ccc ddd".split(" ");
        String[] arr2 = "111 222 333 444".split(" ");

        StringBuilder text3 = new StringBuilder("");

        for(int i=0;i<arr1.length; i++) {
            text3.append(arr1[i]).append(arr2[i]).append("\n");
        }


        TextArea textArea3 = new TextArea();
        textArea3.setText(text3.toString());
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants, I understand that your answer is based on the way the question was originally formatted but if you try to edit the question then you can see what is actually being asked.

Comment: It is exacly what i want :) Thanks m8

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, (including java 8 streams etc)

for you can be better to use `String#split()`, then append all those using a `StringBuilder` object

**example**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "aaa bbb ccc ddd";
    String b = "111 222 333 444";

    String[] aArray = a.split("\n");
    String[] bArray = b.split("\n");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < bArray.length; i++) {
        sb.append(aArray[i]);
        sb.append(bArray[i]);
        sb.append("\n");
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Does this take into account that OP wants to append `textArea1` and `textArea2` by lines? I.e. append with delimiter `\n`.

Comment: Hi @px06 thanks... now I see the well formatted question better ;)

Comment: This only works if the split Strings have the exact same length.

Comment: well, if OP dosnt provide specific Details then is his own fault.. ;) we are not suggesting Soft Arch anyways but concrete Solutions to a soft problems....

Comment: Offtopic, but what exactly is the meaning if your username?